# Building Android.mk on Windows doesn't execute $(shell cp) properly

Tags: android, makefile

I've had an old Windows setup, where during building Android application with `Android.mk` file it successfully run shell commands like

```
$(shell cp $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES) $(TARGET_OUT)/somefile.txt)
```

Unfortunately on a fresh installation of Windows 11 and Android Studio, the `cp` command doesn't work. It doesn't produce any error, it doesn't abort the building process. It just silently doesn't copy the designated files to the designated locations. I tried to print the source/destination arguments of the command, and they seem correct.

Is there any other way to copy files from code of Android.mk?

Comment: `cp` is a tool available on `bash`. If you're using `cmd.exe` or PowerShell you should try running it from within a  WSL environment

Comment: @SomerandomITboy actually `cp` is available in PowerShell too, and my Android Studio seems to use PowerShell. I can copy the files myself using `cp`, but not through `$(shell cp ...)`

Comment: Perhaps the error that the console might be outputting could prove useful

Comment: @SomerandomITboy No error per se, just a silent ignoring of the command and continuation of the build further. Normally if the command were to fail, the build in Android Studio would stop immediately

Comment: If it worked before and doesn't now, then probably on that other system you had the standard POSIX tools on your PATH.  For example, maybe you installed Git for Windows on that system AND asked it to put the POSIX tool directory (e.g., something like `C:\Git\usr\bin` or whatever) on your PATH, so when you run `cp foo bar` from a Windows `cmd.exe`, it worked there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make doesn't use the shell you invoked it with (if it did that, everyone who used a different shell would not be able to use your makefile).

On POSIX systems like Linux and MacOS, it uses `/bin/sh`.  On Windows, by default (but this can be modified when GNU make is compiled) GNU make will first look for `sh` on your PATH and if it's not found, it will use `cmd.exe`.

GNU Make will never use Powershell on Windows (unless you specifically tell it to by setting the `SHELL` makefile variable).

Unfortunately you have not provided enough information for us to help you: you need to give us the context of where the `$(shell ...)` appears.  Is it sitting by itself in the makefile, as you have it?  I'm quite sure that's not the case.  So, it must be in a recipe, and to understand the behavior we'd need to see the recipe.

The `$(shell ...)` function is generally not something you want to use in a recipe.  A recipe is *already* running in a shell so it's redundant, and it has weird behaviors that you wouldn't expect.  The way `$(shell ...)` works is that it runs the command and *expands to* the stdout.  It doesn't display the stdout.  Also, failures in `$(shell ...)` are not considered a failure of the recipe: the exit code is ignored.